# Sencha Grid - How to add/remove columns based on a condition dynamically without knowing order

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Sencha grid where I want to be able to add or remove a column based on some criteria but don't want to rely on knowing the order.  I would like to preferably do this using name, or dataIndex, etc so that the solution is not tied to the column ordering.  I tried looking at things like columnManager, which is the closest thing to what I am looking for but it is private and not recommended in production code.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For my understand, you want to dynamically create the columns based on the data you can get, right?

You can use grid.reconfigure([store], [columns]) method which [columns] is the config object. You can modify the object as your requirement.